# How can I upgrade my ubuntu system from the command line?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I'm running Lucid Lynx and I would like to upgrade to the Meerkat version.

Which command can I use from the terminal to download and perform this upgrade?

I've tried `sudo apt-get upgrade` but that just seems to update any packages I have installed, and not the actual system itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` but that didn't work for me.

Canonical says to just run `update-manager` and choose the Upgrade button on the topright ish of the window.

Comment: `update-manager -d`will upgrade to the current development version, not to 10.10 !

Comment: AFAIK, it just says that, but upgrades you to the final 10.10 anyway.

Comment: In any case, there is no reason to use the "-d" option and take the risk, as update-manager will provide the upgrade button by default if there is a new release available...

Comment: It's kinda odd then that a lot of the documentation floating around the web includes -d.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/upgrade

Comment: The key point from within there: `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade system from the command line, use these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't upgrade to the next release version.